# Getting a value with 2 keys between 2 maps

Tags: java

I have a twoKeys class that has equal() and hashcode() and 2 data wrapper.
Now, in my service class how can I call the 2 keys with 1 value. The 1st will be hard coded and the other will be iterated. What code do I need to do this?

```
data1Wrapper wrapper = new data1Wrapper(data1);
data2Wrapper wrapper2 = new data2Wrapper(data2);
Map<String, List<data1>> maps1 = wrapper.getData();
Map<twoKeys, List<data2>> maps2 = wrapper2.getData();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<data1>> entry1 : maps1.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry1.getKey();
        List<data2> values1 = entry1.getValue();
// I have a problem below this line about calling the value with 2 keys
        List<data2> values2 = maps2.get(key);
        compareData(values1, values2);
    }
```

The 1st key is "APPROVED" or "DENIED" and the 2nd key will be unique ID.

twoKeys

```
private String status;
private String uid;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String part) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "twoKeys{" + "status=" + status + ", uid=" + uid + '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    twoKeys key = (twoKeys) obj;
    return status.equals(key.status)
            && uid.equals(key.uid);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 1;
    hash = hash * 23 + (status == null ? 0 : status.hashCode());
    hash = hash * 23 + (part == null ? 0 : uid.hashCode());
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: How can your getData method return two different types of values? Map<String, List<data1>> and Map<twoKeys, List<data2>>. What is twoKeys here?

Comment: twoKeys is a class that has setters and getters, boolean equals() and hashcode(). For your question I'll be including the codes of twoKeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass String object while retrieving the value from map2 when the expected key type is twoKeys class.

You will have to create your twoKeys object using your constructor may be something like this,

```
twoKeys twoKeysObj = new twoKeys("somestatus", "someuid");
```

And then you will be able to call method like this,

```
List<data2> values2 = maps2.get(twoKeysObj );
```

instead of this,

```
List<data2> values2 = maps2.get(key);
```

Hope this helps.

Edit1:

You need to make this constructor in your twoKeys class.

```
    public twoKeys(String status, String uid) {
        this.status = status;
        this.uid = uid;
    }
```

Or if you don't want to create this constructor then you can do this,

```
    twoKeys twoKeysObj = new twoKeys();
    twoKeysObj.setStatus("somestatus");
    twoKeysObj.setUid("someuid");
```

Comment: I already did this but I got this run time exception. 
required: no arguments
found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You have to make appropriate constructor. Let me update my answer to include the constructor you need to make. Or you can create your twoKeys object with default constructor and then call setStatus and setUid method to set values and then use your twoKeys object.

Comment: I got this code in my wrapper. 

    twoKeys twoKeysObj = new twoKeys();
    twoKeysObj.setStatus("somestatus");
    twoKeysObj.setUid("someuid");

Comment: Then you should be able to pass twoKeyObj in map2 to get the values. Like this List<data2> values2 = maps2.get(twoKeysObj ); and this should work fine  for you.

Comment: I just edited the codes in my wrapper to meet the condition and now it works.

Comment: Glad to help you :)